# Unity Game view is black

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk

I have created very small project with Unity with one button and one slate.
When I open Game tab - its not showing anything but the black.
Any package or setting is missing?

Screen 1 -
[image]

Screen 2 -

[image]

---

***I have downloaded example and when I open that its showing preview in game view tab.***
Screen attached -
[image]

Comment: Is your camera facing the right way. Did you add your scene to your build?

Comment: Yes, camera looks fine and scene is added in build.

Comment: Even though its same if I create new project

Comment: I got the issue - when I drag drop button, its adding button somewhere else and not near to the MrtkInputSimulator. So when I move button next to MrtkInputSimulator its showing button. Do you know why this is happening?